# An *empty* PHP file "<?php", when included, doesn't get parsed and is added to Output Buffer instead, why so?

Tags: php, include, require, output-buffering

The simplest way to replicate is through a web context, by doing:

1. Create a `file.php` with the following contents: `<?php`. **No whitespace!**
2. Make `index.php` with the following contents:

   ```
   <?php

   header('Content-Type: text/plain');

   require 'file.php';

   echo 'test';
   ```

Now, witness the results.

Expected: `test`

Actual: `<?phptest`

I've stumbled upon this quite some times while developing, and it's quite annoying.

Environment:

- Linux 3.13.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 24 20:06:08 CET 2014 x86_64
- Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) (built: Mar 16 2014 12:48:23)
- PHP 5.5.10 (cli) (built: Mar 5 2014 17:41:10)

Why such behavior, how come PHP doesn't parse this?

Comment: What happens if you have a single whitespace character after `<?php`? It should work then..... the php open tag requires that whitespace (whether a space or a newline).... in the same way that `<?phpecho 'HELLO WORLD';?>` would also fail

Comment: I know it works that way, the question is not about "how to make it work", but as a research behind "why it does not".

Comment: I thought I had answered.... the php open tag isn't just `<?php`, it's `<?php ` with that whitespace character as an essential part of the open tag.... without that whitespace, then it's just a block of text

Comment: @jolt isn't the question, why do you need such an empty file? I don't see any case someone would like to include an empty file.

Comment: The file is part of my applications bootstrap process. The process loosely follows the concept of [*SoC*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) to keep things tidy - therefore, event registration comes from `events.php`, view composers from `vcomposers.php` and macro registrations from `macros.php` (Laravel context). When I'm starting a new project, I start with this boilerplate structure, that, by default is empty. And yes, I just added `IoC` registrations to a separate file, and, due to my pedantic nature, I left no whitespace in it, which in return caused the *bug*.

Comment: This was the single most crazy mind-bending bug I have ever encountered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php):

> **Note:**
>
> In PHP 5.2 and earlier, the parser does not allow the `<?php` opening tag to be the only thing in a file. This is allowed as of PHP 5.3 **provided there are one or more whitespace characters after the opening tag**.

my emphasis